# C++ multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Please don't question the really odd hierarchy of workers in this code here, I have no idea why anyone would want something like this, but I decided to give myself an exercise in Multiple Inheritance, just to be sure I fully understood it.  So here's the result.

```
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    string getname()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setname(string name2)
    {
        name = name2;
    }
    Employee(string name2)
    {
        name = name2;
    }
    Employee(){}
};

class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
    string getname()
    {
        return ("Manager" + name);
    }
    Manager(string name2) : Employee(name2){}
    Manager() : Employee(){}
};

class Supervisor : public Manager,public Employee
{
public:
    Supervisor(string name2) : Manager(name2) , Employee(name2){}
    Supervisor() : Manager() , Employee(){}
    string getname()
    {
        return ("Supervisor" + Employee::getname());
    }
};
```

Hopefully you're understanding what I'm trying to do here.  I'm getting something about an "ambiguous conversion between derived class 'Supervisor' and base class 'Employee.'"  So what do I do?

Comment: "Hopefully you're understanding what I'm trying to do here." You might be better off *explaining* what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why does supervisor inherit from manager ?

Comment: @Justin : The more pertinent question, since `Manager` inherits from `Employee`, is why does `Supervisor` inherit from `Employee` instead of just `Manager`?

Comment: I see no actual *question* here?

Comment: @ildjarn No, because supervisor and manager have no relation at all, they both inherit 'name' from employee but supervisor inherits nothing from manager..

Comment: @Justin : It makes it so that `Supervisor` _is-a_ `Manager`, which is important for any realistic dynamic polymorphism usage.

Comment: You are correct, it's been awhile my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the way you have defined `Supervisor` class, its object will have two subjects of type `Employee`, each coming from it base classes. That is causing problem.

The solution is to use [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) (assuming you need multiple inheritance) as:

```
class Manager : public virtual Employee
```

Hope you note the `virtual` keyword here. :-)

Comment: You should of course only use virtual inheritance if you can't refactor the diamond out.  And here the inheritance of 'Employee' by `Supervisor` is *utterly* superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

You need a virtual inheritance in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    string getname()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setname(string name2)
    {
        name = name2;
    }
    Employee(string name2)
    {
        name = name2;
    }
    Employee(){}
};

class Manager : public virtual Employee
{
public:
    string getname()
    {
        return ("Manager" + name);
    }
    Manager(string name2) : Employee(name2){}
    Manager() : Employee(){}
};

class Supervisor : public Manager,public virtual Employee
{
public:
    Supervisor(string name2) : Manager(name2) , Employee(name2){}
    Supervisor() : Manager() , Employee(){}
    string getname()
    {
        return ("Supervisor" + Employee::getname());
    }
};
```

This problem is also known as Diamond inheritance problem:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Comment: Thanks.  Took me a little while, cos I didn't realize supervisor also had to inherit virtually from Employee at first!

Answer (score 3):

Everybody has already covered virtual inheritance, but I'd suggest reading the C++ FAQ as well.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

`Supervisor` contains two objects of type Employee, the direct one and the one over Manager. It is ambiguous to call `Employee` methods on a `Supervisor` in consequence (*which* Employee should be called?). You might want to employ virtual multiple inheritance instead.